No DNS after installing wireguard + mullvad
I followed these instructions to install wireguard https://mullvad.net/en/help/easy-wireguard-mullvad-setup-linux
I downloaded config files and placed them in /etc/wireguard/config. I ran the command
wg-quick up config_file_name
inside /etc/wireguard/config as root.
My outputs are:
[#] ip link add ca-mtr-wg-004 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf ca-mtr-wg-004 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.70.65.136/32 dev ca-mtr-wg-004
[#] ip -6 address add fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::7:4187/128 dev ca-mtr-wg-004
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev ca-mtr-wg-004
[#] resolvconf -a ca-mtr-wg-004 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set ca-mtr-wg-004 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -6 route add ::/0 dev ca-mtr-wg-004 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip6tables-restore -n
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev ca-mtr-wg-004 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n

Now I can't access the internet.
ping google.com times out (failure in name resolution).
Using a web browser, I get a DNS error.
wg handshake command works
interface: ca-mtr-wg-004
  public key: <hidden by me>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 48800
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: <hidden by me>
  endpoint: <hidden by me>
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
  latest handshake: 4 seconds ago
  transfer: 92 B received, 324 B sent

But connection to mullvad times out:
root@pi:/etc/wireguard# curl https://am.i.mullvad.net/connected
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: am.i.mullvad.net

What can be happening here?
Edit: also wg-quick down <...> makes the system freeze
root@pi:/etc/wireguard# wg-quick down ca-mtr-wg-001
[#] ip -4 rule delete table 51821
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0



Can you connect by IP? E.G., a) ping 142.250.80.78 rather than google.com  b). Can browser connect to 142.250.80.78, rather than google.com? 2. If the IP connection works, then set DNS resolution to another provider, such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) or https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns


I am able to successfully ping 142.250.80.78, but not access it in a web browser (Chromium). I updated  /etc/resolv.conf to have cloudfare's DNS and that seems to make it work now! Why Mullvad sets the DNS server to something totally non-functional is weird...

Then if that worked for you, I'll make it an answer.

Is the issue that DNS resolution fails, but you can connect by IP address? Try the following tests.

In terminal, try to ping a known IP address directly. E.G., ping 142.250.80.78 rather than www.google.com
Can a browser connect to Google by entering 142.250.80.78 in the URL bar?

If the IP connection works, then likely the changes blocked the previous DNS resolver. Set the DNS nameserver to another provider, such as

Cloudflare (1.1.1.1)

or

Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8)

N.B.
Some internet service providers block outside DNS nameservers. At a local public library, I had to set up Automatic DNS resolution to use the internet there.
